# Playing Multiple Sounds Sequently in Android

Tags: android, audio

Well my problem is I have about 12 sounds and the same number of images. What I want to do is playing a sound with its corresponding image and when the sound finishes, play the next sound with the next image and so on until all the sounds have been played, I mean, one after another, not all at the same time.

All of them are short sounds, so I`m using SoundPool.

Can anybody help me, please?. Thank you in advance.

Here is the code, sorry, I forgot include it...

```
String[] flauta = new String[]{"flauta_do","flauta_re","flauta_mi","flauta_fa","flauta_sol","flauta_la","flauta_si","flauta_do_agudo","flauta_re_agudo","flauta_mi_agudo","flauta_fa_agudo","flauta_sol_agudo"};
String[] pentagrama = new String[]{"pentagrama_do","pentagrama_re","pentagrama_mi","pentagrama_fa","pentagrama_sol","pentagrama_la","pentagrama_si","pentagrama_do_agudo","pentagrama_re_agudo","pentagrama_mi_agudo","pentagrama_fa_agudo","pentagrama_sol_agudo"};
String[] nota = new String[]{"Do","Re","Mi","Fa","Sol","La","Si","Do alto","Re alto","Mi alto","Fa alto","Sol alto"};
String[] sonido = new String[]{"sonido_do","sonido_re","sonido_mi","sonido_fa","sonido_sol","sonido_la","sonido_si","sonido_do_agudo","sonido_re_agudo","sonido_mi_agudo","sonido_fa_agudo","sonido_sol_agudo"};

private SoundPool sPool;

ImageView flautaIV;
ImageView pentagramaIV;
TextView notaTV;

int resID = 0;
String recurso = "";
int sonidoNota = 0;



@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_repasar);

        flautaIV = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.flautaIV);
        pentagramaIV = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pentagramaIV);
        notaTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.notaTV);

        sPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);


        for(int i = 0; i < flauta.length; i++)
        {
            recurso = flauta[i];

            resID = getResources().getIdentifier(recurso, "drawable", getPackageName());

            flautaIV.setImageResource(resID);

            recurso = pentagrama[i];

            resID = getResources().getIdentifier(recurso, "drawable", getPackageName());

            pentagramaIV.setImageResource(resID);

            notaTV.setText(nota[i]);

            recurso = sonido[i];

            resID = getResources().getIdentifier(recurso, "raw", getPackageName());

            sonidoNota = sPool.load(this, resID, 1);

            sPool.play(sonidoNota, (float)1.0, (float)1.0, 1, 0, 1f);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Please show the code you have

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify but I'm assuming that all of the sounds are playing at the same time, roughly?

`SoundPool.play` doesn't block so it's immediately wrapping around your loop, loading up the next sound and then playing that. Since you've initialized the `SoundPool` with `1` for the `maxStreams` parameter I'm not exactly sure what behavior you're going to get when it tries to load the next stream before the previous has completed. In any case, you'd need to be able to block after the `play` call until the stream completes. `SoundPool` doesn't have that ability to the best of my knowledge. I think you're going to need to use the `MediaPlayer` which allows you to define an `onCompletionListener`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, how would you change my code to do it with MediaPlayer and its listener?